# Calling PostgreSQL procedures or functions from QGIS' Query Builder

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, query

I am trying to call either a stored procedure or function defined in the PostgreSQL/PostGIS database and use it from the QGIS Query Builder.
Neither work:

- the function returns a table that cannot be interpreted by the Query Builder
- the procedure, which returns a selection, fails when I call it using the `call` instruction

Both work well in DataGrip and query a tag from a `tag` text-array column in the `waypoints` table.

Here is the function:

```sql
create or replace function gwd(t text)
RETURNS TABLE (f_ogc_fid int, f_name text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    return query
        SELECT ogc_fid,name::text
        FROM gis.gps.waypoints
        where tag @> STRING_TO_ARRAY(t, ',');
end;
$$
```

Here is the procedure which fails at the `CALL` in QGIS' Query Builder:

```sql
create or replace procedure grw(T text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM gis.gps.waypoints
        where tag @> STRING_TO_ARRAY(T, ',');
end;
$$
```

Here is the error reported by QGis when I execute `call grw('iron')` in the Query Builder:

```
An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "grw"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "gps"."waypoints" WHERE call grw('iron') LIMIT...
```

When I call it without the `CALL`, it does not work either:

```
An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
ERROR:  grw(unknown) is a procedure
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "gps"."waypoints" WHERE grw('iron') LIMIT 0
HINT:  To call a procedure, use CALL.
```

Comment: Why do you want to use it in the Query Builder? Or do you mean the "Execute and load SQL"?

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

- A `PRODECURE` is a *transaction aware procedural statement*,
  introduced in PG 11, to accomodate for the missing transaction
  control in a normal `FUNCTION` block.

  **However**, a `PROCEDURE` **cannot return values**, and anything else than directly calling it with (*nothing else but*)

  ```
  CALL <procedure>;
  ```

  cannot work. You want to use a `PROCEDURE` whenever
  you want to **execute DDL statements** on your relations **with
  transaction control**, while handling errors during execution more
  elegantly. Semantically, what you are looking for **is a `FUNCTION`**
- The *Query builder* dialog allows to quickly add filter expressions
  on the data source.

  **However**, QGIS translates these filters into **provider specific syntax**, meaning that, in case of a PostgreSQL/PostGIS source layer,
  it will add these statements to a base query in the form of

  ```
  SELECT * FROM "<schema>"."<table>" WHERE <FILTER>;
  ```

  where
  `<FILTER>` is **the precise expression entered into the dialog
  field**
- In any way, your attempts are pointless (no offense) for the way you intend to
  use them:

  - it doesn't make sense to filter a table for a tag to use the returned rows/values as the same filter for the same table
  - and *if* you wanted to do that, you'd need to again define a filter expression to *use* the returned rows/values

---

**The simplest solution** would be to just (*and only*) enter

```
'iron' = ANY(tag)
```

**into the *Query builder* expression field**; this translates into

```
SELECT * FROM "gps"."waypoints" WHERE 'iron' = ANY(tag);
```

which you can use in SQL directly if needed.